# Is there are way to read .string files for StringTemplate in C#

Tags: c#, localization, stringtemplate

I found one sample in StringTemplate documentation to read *.resx embedded resource, but it is not actually that I expect.

http://www.stringtemplate.org/article/i18n/index.html - there is a sample of making it in Java. Did anybody made it working on C#?